# Atom Language Definition using nested Regex patterns

Tags: regex, coffeescript, grammar, atom-editor

I am actually trying to define a grammar in Atom (which goes surprisingly well) and, after 3 days of fiddling with Regex, get the feeling to slowly going nuts.

The problem is that I now leave the field of "simple" definitions, so I also need a far better knowledge on regular expressions than I have now.

**Question:**
I want to match 4 specific patterns using `begin` and `end`.
Through Textmate tutorials I learned that the behaviour should be somwhat like:

`begin: \w`,`end: \d` becomes `\w(.*)\d`

Using this knowledge, I want to match these four expressions:

1. `foo( a(1) )`: resolves to a scope which is nested "in itself" (the same way as described for `qq`-Strings in the [TextMate Language Example](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars).
2. `bar(1)('a')`: resolves to a scope `bar` which is accessed by the field `(1)` and therefore field `('a')`. `bar` has this scope only under the condition that at least a second parenthesis block is present.
3. `foo( bar(1)('a') )`: A mixture of (1) and (2). `foo` is extracted (1), `bar` represents the same thing as described in (2).
4. `foo( bar(1)('a')('a') )('a')`: The most complex one. `foo` represents an element which can be extracted by using the second parenthesis, `bar` represents something which can be extracted by the same mechanism and yield a value which may access `foo` without further problems at runtime.

To catch all of those statements I now have two regular expressions (CSON-syntax follows):

```coffee
'strange_accessors':
{
  'comment': 'tries to catch foo(a)(a)(a) constructs'
  'begin': '(?:' +
             '(?:(?<=\\))\\s*)'         + # closing parenthesis beforehand
             '|(?:[\\w%\\$\\?!#]*)'  + # character beforehand
           ')' +
           '\\s*'   +
           '(\\()'  +  # opening bracket
           '[^;]+?' +
           '(\\))'  +
           '\\s*(\\()'
  'end': '(\\))+?'

  'beginCaptures':
    '1':
      'name': 'punctuation.parens.begin.someLang'
    '2':
      'name': 'punctuation.parens.someLang'
    '3':
      'name': 'punctuation.parens.begin.someLang'
  'endCaptures':
    '0':
      'name': 'punctuation.parens.end.someLang'
}
```

So, to catch the surronding parenthesis, I use this:

```coffee
'surronding_parenthesis':
{
  'comment': 'describes a (nested) accessor using parenthesis'
  'begin':  '(?:[a-zA-Z_%\\$\\?!#][\\w%\\$\\?!#]*)'  + # character beforehand
           '(\\()'
  'end': '(?>(\\)))'

  'beginCaptures':
    '1':
      'name': 'punctuation.section.parens.begin.someLang'
  'endCaptures':
    '1':
      'name': 'punctuation.section.parens.end.someLang'
    '2':
      'name': 'banana.invalid.illegal.someLang'

  'patterns':[
    { 'include': '#strange_accessors'}
  ]

}
```

I was fiddling my way through greedy, reluctant and posessive behaviour, as well as atomic groups, because I think this will be the key to a good match.

But I am fully confust and don't really know how to solve this strange nesting problem. If somebody is interested and wants to try why I need this:

It's a grammar for [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/).

Comment: Where is the recursion ? Example Pcre `(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))`

Comment: Just tried and it matches the patterns in all unique parenthesis. But what I want is something more like

`foo(foo(b))('a')` resolves to `foo(...)('a')` as well as `foo(b)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex below uses recursion:

```
(?<=\s)\w+(\(((?:[^()]+|(?1))*?)\))(\('.*?'\))?
```

It will match

```
  foo( a(1) )
  bar(1)('a')
  foo( bar(1)('a') )
  foo( bar(1)('a')('a') )('a')
```

You can test it [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eS0fM2/1)
(Scilab uses the PCRE regex engine from what I read on a forum)

Notice that it contains the positive lookbehind `(?<=\s)` to assure there's a whitespace before the leading word.
Because I doubted that you want to match something like `\b( a(1) )`

This regex will also match them, but without recursion. Just using non-capture groups:

```
(?<=\s)\w+\((?:.*?(?:\(.*?\))?)+\)(?:\('.*?'\))?
```

Comment: Thank you very much - not exactly what I was looking for, but from this I can expand it myself.

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped. But if you would add some sample source text that would help with finding the right solution ;)

Comment: Is it maybe that you were really looking for the foo and bar? In that case just replace the `\w+` by `(?:foo|bar)`

Comment: No, it is really more like a "nested" extraction.
Here is why I need this:
Scilab has some builtin type they call 'struct' (I think short for structured list), which you can both access using dot (,) or parenthesis. Appearently, I cannot differntiate in between struct or a "normal" extraction (if parenthesis are used), but for one case:
A `struct` can be extracted successfully.
That means `foo(a)` (where `a` represents a variable) can only be a struct if `a` is of type string, but `foo(1)(a)` must be a structure by grammar definition. And of course as a scripter you want to nest it ;)

Comment: So for the Atom grammar I basically aim to catch the insights of the two outermost found parenthesis and will then use the same pattern to catch stuff inside. A quick test looks promising.